# Swift: different xibs layouts for one UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to use more then one xib Layout for a UICollectionViewCell. Let's say i have a xib Layout with textfields only, let's call it "textfield.xib" and one xib with only images, "image.xib". In the collectionViewDelegate function cellForItemAtIndexPath I declare two Cells like the following Code:

```
cell:ImageCell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell
cell:TextFieldCell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextFieldCell
```

The problem now is how to register the nibs. AFAIK I can register only one nib for one collectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect; you can register as many cells as you want. You should give them different identifiers though, both when you register them, and also in cellForItemAtIndexPath.